# Direct sum of categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, direct-sum

Is there a notion of a direct sum of two categories?
E.g. let $A$ be an algebra, $\text{Rep} A$ the category of finite dimensional left $A$-modules and $\text{Vect}$ the category of finite dimensional vector spaces (of a fixed field, the same as for $\text{Rep} A$).

What would $\text{Rep} A\oplus \text{Vect}$ mean?

Comment: You can form a Cartesian product of categories in the obvious way:  objects are pairs of objects, morphisms are pairs of morphisms. Or are you trying to form some sort of internal direct sum of "orthogonal" subcategories?

Comment: So the definition of a direct sum of two categories is the same as the Cartesian product of them?

Comment: What does direct sum even mean?

Comment: Well, that's the question.  I just read this sign $\oplus$ between two categories.

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing it means what I said:  category of pairs.  Maybe someone else can confirm or deny.

Comment: Let us call that direct sum $S=S_1\otimes S_2$. A tensor product functor is defined on $S$ as follows: For $X,Y\in F$ the tensor product is defined by distinguishing $4$ cases (whether $X$ and $Y$ are in $S_1$ or $S_2$). Why is it enough to define the functor on that?

Comment: Well, direct sum might also refer to *coproduct*, i.e. simply *disjoint union* of the given categories in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘refer to coproduct’? It is not clear to me since usually coproduct makes sense of objects in a category and not of two categories.

Comment: You can view (locally small) categories as objects in a (large) category of (locally small) categories.

Comment: @Berci: You'd still have to specify what category to take coproducts in. In the category of abelian categories, the disjoint union of two objects doesn't even produce an object of the category!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's only one reasonable notion of direct sum of additive categories, like the module categories in your example. $A\oplus B$ has objects the pairs $(a,b)$ and morphisms $(A\oplus B)((a,b),(a',b'))=A(a,a')\oplus B(b,b')$. This has the universal property of a product in the category of additive categories, but unfortunately not of a coproduct in general. There aren't even natural inclusions $A, B\to A\oplus B$ unless $A$ and $B$ have zero objects. In that case you have additive fully faithful embeddings $a\mapsto (a,0_B)$ etc, and every object $(a,b)$ becomes the biproduct $(a,0_B)\oplus (0_A,b)$. This says that the inclusions of and projections on $A$ and $ B$ satisfy a categorified biproduct identity 
$$i_Ap_A\oplus i_Bp_B\cong \mathrm{id}_{A\oplus B}$$
It's not much work now to show that we have canonical equivalences, even isomorphisms, of categories $\mathrm{Add}(C,A\oplus B)\cong \mathrm{Add}(C,A)\oplus \mathrm{Add}(C,B)$ for any $C$. If $C$ has biproducts, then we also get the dual identity $\mathrm{Add}(A\oplus B,C)\cong \mathrm{Add}(A,C)\oplus\mathrm{Add}(B,C)$. So $A\oplus B$ satisfies the universal properties of the biproduct in the category, or really, the 2-category, of additive categories with biproducts. The latter then becomes the canonical example of an "additive 2-category."

Comment: Thank you! In your definition of the morphism, is this a direct sum of vector spaces? (So here you use that the category is additive) That’s it?

Comment: In general, it should be a direct sum of abelian groups.