# Is the product of two abelian categories also abelian?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'd like to know if/when the product of two abelian categories is also an abelian category. I've seen statements in a few places that make me think that it is true, like this question [Coproduct of abelian categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087683/coproduct-of-abelian-categories). It sounds like I would at least have to be working in the 2-category of abelian categories.

I started trying to prove it from the definition of abelian category, but it seemed like I was just moving symbols around and perhaps missing the point.

Comment: Do you mean the [tensor product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23278/tensor-product-of-abelian-categories) of abelian categories, or the Cartesian product?

Comment: Cartesian product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the product of two abelian categories is abelian.  The proof is basically trivial: all of the notions used in the definition of an abelian category (zero objects, kernels, cokernels, monics, etc.) can be checked separately on each coordinate when you have a product of categories (so for instance, $(A,B)$ is a zero object iff both $A$ and $B$ are zero objects, and $(f,g):(A,B)\to(C,D)$ is a kernel of $(h,i):(C,D)\to(E,F)$ iff $f$ is a kernel of $h$ and $g$ is a kernel of $i$).  So, if both coordinates satisfy all the axioms for an abelian category, so will the product category.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful! I think the triviality of the proof just made me think I was missing something.